# open a html modal programmatically in React

Tags: reactjs

I have this two elements a button and a dialog

```
<dialog className='w-11/12 shadow-none rounded-tl-md rounded-tr-md lg:rounded-lg absolute'>wqdwe</dialog>

<button className=" px-6 py-2 rounded absolute mt-12 ml-12" onClick={} >Click</button>
```

How can I open the dialog on clicking the button in React

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  showModals(){
this.myRef.showModal();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
   //this.showModals()
  }
```

EDIT: I am trying to access the `.showModal()` method in the dialog according to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog. How can I do that, I need the dimmed background feature when the modal is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `componentDidMount` nor `useRef` with the `state` and using the props `open` of the `dialog` you can show it conditionally.

1. first solution using `isOpen` is the `state`

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
   render() {
    return (
      <dialog style={{width: "80%", height: "80%", marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: '#eee'}}
        open={this.props.open}
        >
        <p>Greetings, one and all!</p>
      </dialog>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  
  switchModal = (prevState) => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return { isOpen: !prevState.isOpen }
    });
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.switchModal}>
          {this.state.isOpen ? 'Close' : 'Open'} Modal 
        </button>
        <br/>
        <Modal open={this.state.isOpen}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

2. second solution using native `showModal` method. With this method you can use  the css property `dialog::backdrop`.

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
 
   render() {
    return (
      <dialog id='modal' style={{width: "80%", height: "80%", marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: '#eee'}}
        >
        <p>Greetings, one and all!</p>
        <button onClick={this.props.closeModal}>
          Close Modal 
        </button>
      </dialog>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  
  switchModal = (prevState) => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      if(!prevState.isOpen) {
        document.getElementById('modal').showModal()
      } else {
        document.getElementById('modal').close()
      }
      return { isOpen: !prevState.isOpen }
    });
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.isOpen && <button onClick={this.switchModal}>
          Open Modal 
        </button>}
        <br/>
        <Modal 
          closeModal={this.switchModal}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
dialog {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I added a second solution working with `dialog::backdrop`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [React state API](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) to show and hide components based on actions taken elsewhere in the code.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      isDialogVisible: false
    }
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isDialogVisible: !this.state.isDialogVisible })
  }

  render() {
    const { isDialogVisible } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>{isDialogVisible ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} dialog</Button>
        {this.state.isDialogVisible && <Dialog />}
      </div>
   )
 }
}
```