# Function to replace alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to roll my own custom alert, but don't want to touch the render or state of components that currently call the default window.alert().

I'm using React 15.x

```
function injectDialogComponent(message: string){
const modal = <Modal>{message}</Modal>
document.body.appendChild(modal) //this errors, but how would I do something like this?
}
```

I've tried 
`ReactDOM.render(modal,document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div)`
but doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what are you trying to do exactly ? why can't you use `alert` ?

Comment: Edited - I'm trying to replace alert with my own custom Modal with the constraint that it should have the same api and work within a React context

Comment: Then I don't think you should use `document.body.appendChild`. Use React's `state` to show or hide the modal : have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61558739/open-a-html-modal-programmatically-in-react/61559083#61559083)

Comment: That's the thing I don't want to touch the state or render function of the components that call this custom alert

Comment: Does my answer works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create you html node, append it to you root element and then append your React `<Modal>` in you newly created `div` modal :

```js
React.render(<Modal>{message}</Modal>, document.getElementById('modal'))
```

```js
class Modal extends React.Component { 
   render() {
    return (
      <dialog id='modal' style={{width: "80%", height: "80%", marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: '#eee'}} open
        >
        <p>{this.props.children}</p>
      </dialog>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  
  openModal = message => {
    let modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.id = 'modal';
    document.getElementById('root').appendChild(modal)
    React.render(<Modal>{message}</Modal>, document.getElementById('modal'));
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.openModal("Hello")}>Open Modal</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```